# javascript - organize array of objects based on property of nested array

Tags: javascript

I have an nested array of `animals`, and I would like to organize them into a map based on the `animal` `color`.

original data

```
const animals = [
    {
        type: 'dog',
        species: [
            {
                name: 'retriever',
                color: 'yellow',
            },
            {
                name: 'pug',
                color: 'black',
            },
            {
                name: 'lab',
                color: 'white',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        type: 'cat',
        species: [
            {
                name: 'persian',
                color: 'white',
            },
            {
                name: 'shorthair',
                color: 'black',
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

desired output

```
const animalsByColor = {
    black: [
        {
            type: 'dog',
            species: [
                {
                    name: 'pug',
                    color: 'black',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            type: 'cat',
            species: [
                {
                    name: 'shorthair',
                    color: 'black',
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
    white: [
        {
            type: 'dog',
            species: [
                {
                    name: 'lab',
                    color: 'white',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            type: 'cat',
            species: [
                {
                    name: 'persian',
                    color: 'white',
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
    yellow: [
        {
            type: 'dog',
            species: [
                {
                    name: 'retriever',
                    color: 'yellow',
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
};
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Could you show us know what you have tried, and then we can help you improve/fix your code?

Comment: In your example desired result you have an array of Animals sorted by color, not the animal specie name (that you call a "type")

Comment: @AifosSiPrahs sorry about that! I have corrected the post. I do want to organize by color. thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

see it

```js
const animals = [
    {
        type: 'dog',
        species: [
            {
                name: 'retriever',
                color: 'yellow',
            },
            {
                name: 'pug',
                color: 'black',
            },
            {
                name: 'lab',
                color: 'white',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        type: 'cat',
        species: [
            {
                name: 'persian',
                color: 'white',
            },
            {
                name: 'shorthair',
                color: 'black',
            },
        ],
    },
];

const sortedObject = {}


animals.forEach((el)=>{
  el.species.forEach((ael)=>{
  type = el.type;
    name  = ael.name;
    color = ael.color;
    
    //sorted array
    
    if(!Object.keys(sortedObject).includes(color)){
      sortedObject[color] = []
    }
    
    data = {
      type:type,
      species : ael
    }
    sortedObject[color].push(data)
    
  })
})



console.log(sortedObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group with the help of an object which keeps the references for color and type.

```js
const
    animals = [{ type: 'dog', species: [{ name: 'retriever', color: 'yellow' }, { name: 'pug', color: 'black' }, { name: 'lab', color: 'white' }] }, { type: 'cat', species: [{ name: 'persian', color: 'white' }, { name: 'shorthair', color: 'black' }] }],
    references = {},
    animalsByColor = {};

animals.forEach(({ type, species }) => {
    species.forEach(({ name, color }) => {
        references[color] ??= animalsByColor[color] ??= [];
        if (!references[color][type]) references[color].push({ type, species: references[color][type] = []  });
        references[color][type].push({ name, color });
    });
});

console.log(animalsByColor);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group the animals by color, you will need to iterate over the types and inside each type, the list of species.

For each species, you will need the current loop index to filter the species for each item.

I added a simple example in here as well to showcase the functions extensibility.

```js
const animals = [{
  type: 'dog',
  species: [
    { name: 'retriever', color: 'yellow' },
    { name: 'pug', color: 'black' },
    { name: 'lab', color: 'white' },
  ],
}, {
  type: 'cat',
  species: [
    { name: 'persian', color: 'white' },
    { name: 'shorthair', color: 'black' }
  ]
}];

const animalsSimple = [
  { type: 'dog', name: 'retriever', color: 'yellow' },
  { type: 'dog', name: 'pug', color: 'black' },
  { type: 'dog', name: 'lab', color: 'white' },
  { type: 'cat', name: 'persian', color: 'white' },
  { type: 'cat', name: 'shorthair', color: 'black' }
];

const main = () => {
  const groupedByColor = groupBy(
    animals,
    ({ color }) => color,
    'species'
  );
  console.log(groupedByColor);

  const groupedByColorSimple = groupBy(
    animalsSimple,
    ({ color }) => color,
  );
  console.log(groupedByColorSimple);
};

const groupBy = (items, consumer, subKey) =>
  items.reduce((groups, item) => {
    if (subKey) {
      item[subKey].forEach((subItem, index) => {
        applyToGroup(groups, consumer(subItem), item, subKey, index);
      });
    } else {
      applyToGroup(groups, consumer(item), item);
    }
    return groups;
  }, {});

const applyToGroup = (groups, key, item, subKey, index) => {
  const items = groups[key] ?? [];
  if (subKey) {
    items.push({
      ...item,
      [subKey]: item[subKey].filter((_, i) => i === index)
    });
  } else {
     items.push({ ...item });
  }
  groups[key] = items;
}

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Output is a map of  colors as keys and an array of animals  objects as values grouped by type .

```js
    const result = animals.reduce((acc, animalGroup) => {
        animalGroup.species.forEach((specie) => {
            if (!acc[specie.color]) {
                acc[specie.color] = [];
            }
            acc[specie.color].push(animalGroup.species.filter((animal) => animal.color === specie.color));
        });
        return acc;
    }
    , {});
```